# iOS, random swipe with animation

Tags: ios, animation, random, swipe

How to make a random swipe with animation. Right now it's swiping but the new image is not appearing while swiping.

```
- (void)swipeToTheRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

        NSLog(@"Swiped to the right");
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                             [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
                             [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
                             [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
                             [UIView commitAnimations];
                             [self.myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:quoteIndex]]];
                             [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
                         }]; 
}
```

`SwipeToTheLeft`

```
- (void)swipeToTheLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

        NSLog(@"Swiped to the left");
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                         animations:^{
                             [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
                             [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
                             [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
                             [UIView commitAnimations];
                             [self.myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:quoteIndex]]];
                             [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
                         }];


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `[UIView commitAnimations];` line at the end of the block:

```
^{
     [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];

     [self.myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:quoteIndex]]];
     [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
     [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

Comment: It's still the same photo that I do have when load the application. Animation appears but changing of the photo - no

Comment: Everything is OK. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should mix UIView block-based animations (`animateWithDuration`) with old-style `beingAnimations`/`commitAnimations` animations like you are doing. Try getting rid of the `beingAnimations`/`commitAnimations` calls and use the duration of the block animation. Also, I'm not sure if it matters, but I've always called layoutIfNeeded inside my animation block, not `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`.

### EDIT:

So your code should read like this:

```
- (void)swipeToTheRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
  NSLog(@"Swiped to the right");
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
    animations:^
    {
      UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:quoteIndex]];
      [self.myImage setImage: anImage];
      [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }]; 
}
```

The `setAnimationTransition` code you had won't do anything. That only has an effect if you switch views, as described in the Xcode docs in the section on `setAnimationTransition`. Since you're not switching views, it won't do anything.

Also, what is the property `self.myImage`? Is the an image view that is currently in the view hierarchy? If so, "myImage" is a confusing name. It should be "myImageView". Images and image views are quite different, just like views and view controllers are quite different.